# I've got an Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host exception

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, restsharp

i've upgraded to the net core 6 and upgraded RestSharp to the 107.0.3 version.
File upload to OneDrive API (Upload large files with an upload session), i've got an exception *'Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.'*

The first POST call to get a temp upload URL i've received a uploadUrl (**https**://api.onedrive.com/rup/.........). But when i did a call to it, i've got an exception.
[image]

When i downgraded to the RestSharp version 106.15.0 everything is working as expected.

My assumption, it's something wrong with the SSL configuration in HttpClient. Bc, in version 107.x RestSharp change 'HttpWebRequest' to the 'HttpClient'.
https://restsharp.dev/v107/#restsharp-v107

I've can't quickly find a solution to fix this, so I've just downgraded to 106.x version.

Maybe somebody knows a solution and shares it here.

Source code:

```
var resource = "URL";
var request = CreateRequest(accessInfo.Token, resource, Method.POST);
request.AddJsonBody($"{{ \"@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior\": \"replace\", \"name\": \"{fileName}\" }}");
var response = await _graphApiClient.ExecuteAsync(request);
if (!response.IsSuccessful)
     {
     throw GenerateException("Can't create a upload session.", resource, $"{folderPath}/{fileName}", response);
     }

var fileContentType = fileName.GetFileType().GetContentType();
var uploadSessionUrl = Map<FileUploadSession>(response.Content).UploadUrl;
var sessionClient = new RestClient(uploadSessionUrl);
var sessionRequest = new RestRequest(string.Empty, Method.PUT);
sessionRequest.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileBytes.Length.ToString());
sessionRequest.AddHeader("Content-Range", $"bytes 0-{(fileBytes.Length - 1).ToString()}/{fileBytes.Length}");
sessionRequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", fileContentType);
sessionRequest.AddParameter(fileContentType, fileBytes, ParameterType.RequestBody);

var sessionResponse = await sessionClient.ExecuteAsync(sessionRequest);
if (!sessionResponse.IsSuccessful)
        {
            throw GenerateException("can't upload file to session storage.", uploadSessionUrl, $"{folderPath}/{fileName}", response);
        }

private RestRequest CreateRequest(string accessToken, string resource, Method method)
    {
        var request = new RestRequest(resource, method);
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {accessToken}");
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", Constants.ContentTypeJson);
        request.AddHeader("Accept", Constants.ContentTypeJson);
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

        return request;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Few issues with your code:

- You use `AddJsonBody` is for adding objects. RestSharp [documentation](https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#addjsonbody) *explicitly* tells you not to do it
  [image: warning]
- You add lots of headers that RestSharp adds by itself.
- You don't use `AddFile`, which you [should be using](https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#uploading-files) for uploads

A comment, your code seems to be for RS 106, not 107.

Here is the changed code, which I made by hand, so it might not compile.

Overall, it's good to read the docs.

```
var resource = "URL";
var request = CreateRequest(accessInfo.Token, resource, Method.Post);
request.AddStringBody($"{{ \"@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior\": \"replace\", \"name\": \"{fileName}\" }}", ContentType.Json);
var response = await _graphApiClient.ExecuteAsync(request);
if (!response.IsSuccessful)
{
     throw GenerateException("Can't create a upload session.", resource, $"{folderPath}/{fileName}", response);
}

var fileContentType = fileName.GetFileType().GetContentType();
var uploadSessionUrl = Map<FileUploadSession>(response.Content).UploadUrl;
var sessionClient = new RestClient(uploadSessionUrl);
var sessionRequest = new RestRequest(string.Empty, Method.Put);
sessionRequest.AddFile("file", fileBytes, fileName, fileContentType);

var sessionResponse = await sessionClient.ExecuteAsync(sessionRequest);
if (!sessionResponse.IsSuccessful)
{
    throw GenerateException("can't upload file to session storage.", uploadSessionUrl, $"{folderPath}/{fileName}", response);
}

private RestRequest CreateRequest(string accessToken, string resource, Method method)
{
    return new RestRequest(resource, method)
        .AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {accessToken}");
}
```

Comment: yes, my code is for 106 version, bc I've downgraded it. i will investigate and try your code. Thanks!